# Flatten/merge dictionary with nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I've got the following dictionary example:

```
z1 = {
  "ZH": {
    "hosts": {
      "zhsap001.domain.com": {
        "active": "y",
        "ip": "11.111.11.10",
        "zone": "North"
      },
      "zhsap002.domain.com": {
        "active": "y",
        "ip": "11.111.11.11",
        "zone": "North"
      }
    }
  },
  "BE": {
    "hosts": {
      "besap001.domain.com": {
        "active": "y",
        "ip": "22.222.2.20",
        "zone": "Center"
      },
      "besap002.domain.com": {
        "active": "y",
        "ip": "10.214.4.58",
        "zone": "Center"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'd like to "flatten" it to:

```
z2 = {
   "zhsap001.domain.com": {
      "active": "y",
      "ip": "11.111.11.10",
      "zone": "North"
   },
   "zhsap002.domain.com": {
      "active": "y",
      "ip": "11.111.11.11",
      "zone": "North"
   },
   "besap001.domain.com": {
      "active": "y",
      "ip": "22.222.2.20",
      "zone": "Center"
   },
   "besap002.domain.com": {
      "active": "y",
      "ip": "10.214.4.58",
      "zone": "Center"
   }
}
```

I can create `z2` from `z1` by running:

```
z2 = {}
for a in z1.values():
    for b in a.values():
        for (c,d) in b.items():
            z2.update({c:d})
```

But I would like to achieve the same in a more Pythonized manner using a
comprehension expression or lambda function.

Comment: You can use dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could one-line it, but it won't necessarily be more readable that way.

```py
z2 = {c_key: c for a in z1.values() for b in a.values() for c_key, c in b.items()}
```

I'd recommend naming the variables more clearly (I'm guessing what they mean here, you might want to change it)

```py
z2 = {
    url: url_info
    for region in z1.values()
    for host in region.values()
    for url, url_info in host.items()
}
```

Also, you could improve your original code

```py
z2 = {}
for a in z1.values():
    for b in a.values():
        z2 |= b
        # The above requires python >= 3.9, alternatively use the below
        # z2.update(b)
```

Comment: thank you very much!